# How to write an xpath for a dynamic URL

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

The below is the xpath I have written for

```
//form[@data-validate-url='/se/register/validate']
```

But the field data-validate-url changes from time to time e.g

```
data-validate-url= /gb/register/validate 
data-validate-url= /de/register/validate
```

So, how to write an xpath having dynamic content. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply write this xpath using contains() function as below:

```
 //form[contains(@data-validate-url,'/register/validate')]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your url the dynamic part seems `/gb` , `/de` and rest of things are constant Use the CSS locator in following way to handle the same

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form[data-validate-url$='register/validate']"));
```

Also look into these

```
css=form[data-validate-url^='prefix_']

css=form[data-validate-url$=' _suffix']

css=form[data-validate-url*='_pattern_']
```